# rails server cannot start on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This question has been asked many times before but non of  solution is working for me. I have added mysqllib.dll file in ruby/bin, installed mysql2 version 0.3.18 and installed bundle but still getting same error.

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- mysql2/2.2/mysql2 (LoadError)
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/mysql2.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
    from C:/Users/Brendon/Sites/quote/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `require'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in `block in server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the gem and reinstalling it?

Comment: @CaraMcCormack yes i have tried , but its not working

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the path for mysql2 lib in Gemfile

```
gem "mysql2", :path => "/MyPath/MyGem.gem"
```

Comment: i have given path like this " gem "mysql2", : path=>"C:\Ruby22-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\specifications\mysql2-0.3.18-x64-mingw3‌​2.gemspec" but its giving syntax error on line"bundler cannot continue"